# Cómo utilizar el comando echo en Linux

Tags: linux

Quiero mostrar un texto con el comando `echo` y después que me muestre el número de líneas de un archivo.

La sintaxis es algo así:

```
echo El numero de lineas es <wc ejemplo.txt>
```

pero no consigo dar con la sintaxis correcta.

¿Podéis echarme una mano?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Estudiante. Muestranos los intentos que has hecho para que podamos decirte por que te falla o si vas en la direccion acertada. Así sin más es muy amplio. Un saludo

Comment: Hola. "echo El numero de lineas de archivo ejemplo es <wc ejemplo.txt>"

Comment: no entiendo tu comentario. además todo lo relevante ha de estar en el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

La mejor forma de hacer el trabajo es:

```
echo "El número de líneas es $(wc -l < ejemplo.txt)"
```

Necesitas el modificador `-l` que efectúa únicamente un recuento de líneas.

No es necesario usar `cat` para volcar los datos posteriormente mediante una tubería a `wc`, basta con usar `<` para volcar el contenido del archivo directamente a `wc`, y si pasas como argumento el nombre de archivo a `wc` aparecerá éste justo después del recuento de líneas.

---

Prefiero usar el operador [sustitución de órdenes (command substitution)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) `$()` antes que el operador ``` `` ``` porque me permite anidar con facilidad sustitución de órdenes.

Con el operador ``` `` ``` quedaría así:

```
echo "El número de líneas es `wc -l < ejemplo.txt`"
```

Pero como puedes ver en estas pruebas de concepto, es más sencillo usar `$()`:

```
# Mal hecho, es propenso a error anidar con `:
echo "El número de líneas es `cat < `echo ejemplo.txt``"
# Bien hecho, pero hay que aumentar el escapado por cada nivel:
echo "El número de líneas es `cat < \`echo ejemplo.txt\``"
# Bien hecho y, además, más cómodo y legible:
echo "El número de líneas es $(cat < $(echo ejemplo.txt))"
```

Comment: Correcto @OscarGarcia no es necesario el cat, muy buena respuesta. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

para lo que pides podrías utilizar algo así:

```
echo "El numero de lineas es $(cat nombrefichero | wc -l)"
```

En este caso, si utilizases solo wc -l nombrefichero te mostraría en la salida el el numero de líneas y el nombre del fichero. Para evitar esto, utiliza el comando cat, que aprovecha la salida estandar y con | hace que la salida del primero se convierta en la entrada del segundo.

También puedes utilizar lo que dice el compañero arriba:

```
echo El numero de lineas es `cat nombrefichero | wc -l`
```

Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con

```
echo El numero de lineas es `wc -l ejemplo.txt`
```

Esto retornara el numero de lineas ademas del nombre del fichero.

```
El numero de lineas es 80 ejemplo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente, para estos casos *simples*, sin anidamientos, suelo utilizar `echo -n`, que **no realiza** un *cambio de línea*, con lo que lo muestra todo seguido.

```
echo -n 'Número de líneas: '
cat ARCHIVO | wc -l
```

que mostraría lo siguiente:

> Número de lineas: 287

Observa que *encierro* el texto entre *comillas simples* ( ' ), para que tenga en cuenta los espacios.

Answer (score 0):

Para estos casos prefiero utilizar el comando printf en lugar de echo

**ejemplo:**

columns=$(wc -l ejemplo.txt | egrep -o  "^...");

printf "El numero de columnas es:\t%s\n" ${columns}

**salida:**
El numero de columnas es:   200

\t = tabula

%s = La cadena de caracteres que se incluira

\n = salto de linea

que hace el comando egrep?? : extrae los primeros tres caracteres del resultado de *wc -l ejemplo.txt* para que te muestre solo el numero de lineas y no agreege el nombre del fichero.